# How can I delete a row in Cassandra using Apache Flink?

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-flink, cassandra-3.0

In Apache Flink it is easy via `CassandraSink` to insert a row into Cassandra. But I could not find a way to delete a row.

I also tried to write custom sink but I got `NotSerializableException`.
How can I construct a code for delete operation?

```
public class MyCassandraSink implements SinkFunction<String> {

    private Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
            .build();

    private Session cassandra = cluster.connect("mykeyspace");

    @Override
    public void invoke(String value, Context context) throws Exception {
        cassandra.execute("SOME DELETE QUERY");
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: [com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager@3b0fe47a] is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1574)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.addSink(DataStream.java:1227)
    at com.meshkan.streaming.entry.EventListener.main(EventListener.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:973)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:586)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:133)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement your own insert-vs-delete logic, create a sink that extends `CassandraSinkBase`, and implement the `send()` method. See `AbstractCassandraTupleSink` as an example of doing this. Note how `CassandraSinkBase` avoids serialization issues with the Cassandra client by making it transient, and creating it in the `open()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I don't like it. CassandraPojoInputFormat can be used to both DELETE and UPDATE rows. (I also use it for SELECT, which - the name implies - seems like what it was meant to be used for.)

The fact that it works is, IMHO, it's sole redeeming virtue. I'm stuck using this until I find an elegant solution. I'm still looking...

```
CassandraPojoInputFormat<MyThingyConnector> myThingyCassandraPojoInputFormat =
new CassandraPojoInputFormat<MyThingyConnector>(
"DELETE FROM " + dbKeyspace + ".<table_name> <where clause>",
clusterBuilder,
MyThingyConnector.class);

myThingyCassandraPojoInputFormat.configure(null);
myThingyCassandraPojoInputFormat.open(cassandraInputSplit);
myThingyCassandraPojoInputFormat.close();
```